# systemctl status not showing CPU/Memory usage?

Tags: systemd

I used Ubuntu 16.04. And I find some services will show cpu and memory usage via `systemctl status <name>.service`:

```
$ systemctl status nginx
● nginx.service - LSB: Stop/start nginx
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/nginx; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since 五 2017-04-07 09:21:25 CST; 4h 59min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 2677 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/nginx start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Tasks: 2
   Memory: 2.5M
      CPU: 12ms
   CGroup: /system.slice/nginx.service
           ├─2695 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.con
           └─2697 nginx: worker process
```

But on another host, I find the `systemctl status` will not show cpu and memory usage:

```
$ systemctl status nginx
● nginx.service - LSB: Stop/start nginx
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/nginx; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since 四 2017-04-06 20:57:15 CST; 17h ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
   CGroup: /system.slice/nginx.service
           ├─29668 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.con
           ├─29669 nginx: worker process                   
           ├─29670 nginx: worker process                   
           ├─29671 nginx: worker process                   
           └─29672 nginx: worker process
```

Why? Both of the `nginx` were installed from nginx official repo `apt install -y nginx`. Even though on the same host, some services will not show cpu and memory usage.

And how to show the cpu and memory usage in systemctl status?

Comment: After some experimentation I have concluded that this happens on hosts that are upgraded to 16.04. For fresh 16.04 installs both memory and CPU are displayed but not when upgrading from 14.04 so either there are some config done on 14.04 that prevents this or some package that is missing when one upgrades.

Comment: Yes, you're right! But I don't know which package could show theses.

Comment: same here, no idea from [the source code](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/master/src/systemctl/systemctl.c#L4310), I am using systemd 219 from centos7.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have no idea why some hosts could but some couldn't, if you want a consistent behavior, you should enable memory accounting for a single unit or by default for all units by setting:

```
DefaultMemoryAccounting=yes
```

in `/etc/systemd/system.conf` and then doing:

```
systemctl daemon-reexec
```

Check out [this list thread](https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/systemd-devel/2018-July/041093.html) from the systemd developers, and [systemd-system.conf[5]](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-system.conf.html).

Comment: Yes you're right. And I find that if I use `do-release-upgrade` to upgrade from `14.04` to `16.04`, even though I'm not add `DefaultMemoryAccounting=yes` to `/etc/systemd/system.conf`, the `systemctl status` will show cpu and memory usage.

Comment: On Amazon Linux 2, the issue that caused `Memory` to stop displaying on `systemctl status xxx.service` (despite it seeming to work correctly at the kernel level) was caused by running `systemctl enable xxx.service` after starting the service.

Answer (score 7):

Sometimes it might help adding these 2 options in your `<myapp>.service` file under the `[Service]` block

```
CPUAccounting=yes
MemoryAccounting=yes
```

Answer (score 3):

Its actually less complicated 
than you think. To see something non-static like CPU or memory usage, you have to use the command:
 `watch systemctl status <name>.service`